# how to change models field if some row got deleted from database? django

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

I want to check if row got deleted and than update one field for the rest rows with same 'name'

I wrote a method to update field for all rows with same 'name' when new row added, but can not come up with solution for this one

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM school_subjects;
  +----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
    | id | name        | user_id | created_by | created_time        | num_of_followers |
    +----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
    |  1 | Math 140    |       1 |            | 2012-08-06 20:21:38 |                5 |
    |  2 | Math 140    |       2 |            | 2012-08-06 20:22:15 |                5 |
    |  6 | Math 140    |       3 |            | 2012-08-07 20:05:48 |                5 |
    |  4 | Math 140    |       7 |            | 2012-08-07 18:58:14 |                5 |
    |  5 | lalala      |       7 |            | 2012-08-07 18:58:20 |                1 |
    |  7 | Math 140    |       8 |            | 2012-08-07 20:08:03 |                5 |
     ......................................
```

And now if I delete one row, I want the result of num_of_followers to be changed:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | name        | user_id | created_by | created_time        | num_of_followers |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Math 140    |       1 |            | 2012-08-06 20:21:38 |                4 |
 ------------------------------DELETED---------------------------------------------
|  6 | Math 140    |       3 |            | 2012-08-07 20:05:48 |                4 |
|  4 | Math 140    |       7 |            | 2012-08-07 18:58:14 |                4 |
|  5 | lalala      |       7 |            | 2012-08-07 18:58:20 |                1 |
|  7 | Math 140    |       8 |            | 2012-08-07 20:08:03 |                4 |
 ......................................

#models.py
class Subjects(models.Model):
    """ Subject Database """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False) #Subject Names on left-menu 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
  #  updated_time = models.ForeignKey()
    num_of_followers = models.IntegerField()
  #  num_of_documents = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' %(self.name, self.user.username)

    def update_followers(self):
        number = Subjects.objects.filter(name = self.name).count()+1
        Subjects.objects.filter(name= self.name).update(num_of_followers=number)
        return number

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.num_of_followers = Subjects.update_followers(self)
        if not self.id:
            self.created_time = datetime.now()
        self.updated_time= datetime.now()
        super(Subjects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you re-word the question? I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure this level of denormalization is appropriate for this project?

Comment: This level of denormalization seems really... silly. What happens if you change the name of a Subject object. is that then not counted in follower counts? Just what is `Subject` supposed to represent?